# Magento 1.9.3.1 Fatal Error and 3 Warnings

Tags: magento-1, fatal-error

yesterday I got an error on my website, something like "Unable to handle this request". Sadly, I did not backup my website in the last weeks and I didn't want to lose my recent changes by using the backup, so I went to my Webhosts Account and saw that I passed the 50,000 file limit, with about 100 files.
I thought the website's error was because of the host and that they closed my website  because I had more than 50,000 files. To fix the problem I deleted the var/caches, var/reports and var/session folders from Magento. The next day, the error still was there. I pasted this code in my .htacces file, to see what the error was:

```
PHP error handling for development servers
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

php_value error_log /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
[see footnote 3] # php_value error_reporting 999999999
php_value error_reporting -1
php_value log_errors_max_len 0

After pasting the code, my website's error message changed to this:

```
Warning: include_once(/home/tastatur/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php) [function.include-once0]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tastatur/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 36

Warning: include_once() [function.include0]: Failed opening '/home/tastatur/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/tastatur/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/tastatur/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 36

Warning: include(/home/tastatur/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_App.php) [function.include0]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tastatur/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94

Warning: include() [function.include0]: Failed opening '/home/tastatur/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_App.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/tastatur/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/tastatur/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in /home/tastatur/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 670
```

What should I do to fix the errors?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to turn off compilation to fix your error. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi).

To summerize though you can either run the following from the magento root in your cli:

```
php shell/compiler.php disable
```

Or edit `includes/config.php` and comment out the following lines:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Comment: I've done this and now I am able to acces my website, but it seems that my friend can't acces it and gets the same error.

Comment: It could be a cache issue, try clearing all your caches again. I don't see a reason why compilation would be off for one user but not others.